# Cordova(Phonegap) ajax calls hanging on iphone device

Tags: ios, ajax, cordova

The ajax call I made works fine with browser and android, but when running on iphone it hangs on forever, or will be time out if timeout option is added.

The ajax looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://pbcc.ca/xxx/index.php",
  data: {api: 'test'},
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: 'callback',
  beforeSend: function() {
    alert("beforeSend");
  },
  success: function(data) {
    alert("success");
  },
  error: function(e,x) {
    alert("error");
  }
});
```

I tried it after document ready and device ready, only beforeSend responses in both cases. There are several posts of similar problems online and I've tried some methods but none of them solved my problem. Can anyone help? Thanks.

**Update**: Tested on the server side, the server doesn't response to the ajax call from ios. Actually no data transmitted to the server I think.

**Update2**:

I get this error:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://www.pbcc.ca/xxx/index.php?callback=...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://pbcc.ca">
```

Info.plist(I didn't put them together at the beginning):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>pbcc.ca</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

config.xml(default created by cordova):

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.polarbear.lunch" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>xxx</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: Which versions of Cordova and iOS are you using?

Comment: cordova 5.3.3 and ios 9.0.2(iphone 6 plus)

Comment: ? also which methods have you tried, likely if you are on iOS 9 with Cordova 5 you need a combination of Content-Security-Policy setting correctly in your meta tags in index.html AND Apple's App Transport Security exception set up for http://pbcc.ca in your app's Info plist file.

Comment: @SimonPrickett   The Content-Security-Policy setting is default created by cordova. And could you give an example of the Transport Security exception setting? I am new to ios so no idea about that.

Comment: I searched online. Someone says NSAppTransportSecurity should be set, but I didn't find this key in xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 7 will use iOS 9 and that won't allow HTTP backend calls by default unless overridden using NSAllowsArbitraryLoads and disable App Transport Security or configure an exception.

Here's a working example of the change to your app's info .plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

And here's a script you could use as a pre build hook for iOS to do this automatically:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Adjusting plist for App Transport Security exception." val=$(/usr/libexec/plistbuddy -c "add NSAppTransportSecurity:NSAllowsArbitraryLoads bool true" platforms/ios/PROJECTNAME/PROJECTNAME-Info.plist 2>/dev/null) echo "Done"
```

Just swap out PROJECTNAME for the name of your project.

You could also just set an exception for your server only rather than enabling http connections to all backends... to do this use something like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>pbcc.ca</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Additionally you will need to set a connect-src in your Cordova Content Security Policy meta tag in index.html.  Use something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://pbcc.ca">
```

Or use:

```
connect-src *
```

If you want to open up to connecting to anywhere for Ajax calls.  More information on Content Security Policy can be [found here](http://content-security-policy.com/) with a [configuration tool here](http://cspisawesome.com/).

You will need to do BOTH of these changes (Content Security Policy AND App Transport Security exception) to get this working with iOS 9 / Cordova 5 / XCode 7.

In addition from your posted error "Refused to load the script 'http://www.pbcc.ca/xxx/index.php?callback=...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback."

We can see that what's happening is that you're not allowed to load your remote document because it violated your Content Security Policy.  To fix this either set default-src to * or add script-src www.pbcc.ca.  Example:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; connect-src http://pbcc.ca; script-src http://www.pbcc.ca">
```

Note you are mixing and matching www.pbcc.ca and pbcc.ca so you might want to make sure that you specify the right one, or use * to open it up to everything make sure it works then lock it down to the specific host(s).

Comment: Well...still not working. I've added connect-src and NSAppTransportSecurity. I did the following steps to test: 1. cordova build ios --device 2. open the project in xcode and run it on a true device, which is iphone 6+ with IOS9. The debug of xcode shows 0 network data.

Comment: Will be difficult to debug unless you can post your Content-Security-Policy tag in full and the relevant section of your plist.  Probably also your config.xml.  Do you see any errors in the Xcode console, or by attaching the Safari remote debugger and looking at the JS console there then doing a command + R to reload the page and see what if any errors you get?

Comment: Updated the top post, please see 'Update2'

Comment: Updated my answer see script-src section.

Comment: Yep I just figured that out. Thank you again. :)